# how to configure flash player in firefox(flash player is working well in Chrome)?

Tags: flash, firefox

i can view flash videos with chrome in my computer but can't view flash in firefox. plz how to configure firefox to view flash videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome comes bundled with FlashPlayer so you may need to re-install FlashPlayer in order to make it accessible to other browsers.

For instance on my laptop, here's the path to Chrome's bundled FlashPlayer plugin

```
 /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/8.0.552.215/Google 
 Chrome Framework.framework/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player Plugin for Chrome.plugin
```

Here's the path to the player I've downloaded

```
 /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player.plugin
```